# IndexOutOfRangeException upon simple Tab selection

Tags: vb.net, tabs, indexoutofrangeexception

I am experiencing an occasional exception whilst performing a simple Tab selection, referenced by the Tabs Name:

> IndexOutOfRangeException 'Index -1 does not have a value'

The code for selecting a tab:

```vb
With TabControl1
    .SelectTab(.TabPages("TabPageRunning"))
End With
```

I cannot see how this can ever cause an error - the tab index is referenced from the tab name which is only set at design time and not changed subsequently. Even at the point of exception, the tab is clearly still referenced to a valid value in the debugger.

[image]

Comment: When an `IndexOutOfRange` exception is thrown, the obvious first steps are to determine what the index is and what the valid range is.

Comment: Check your spelling of 'TabPageRunning'. It could be that you mispelled it and its returning -1 as the result.

Comment: @Karlta05 Spelling is fine. Also it would not explain why this is intermittent.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I've been waiting to capture the exception to confirm this, however the error seems a bit elusive now. VS had an update applied recently, so will close question if I don't get it again within 7 days.

Comment: I think it may be the way in which you are setting the selected tab. I think it should be .SelectedTab = .TabPages("TabPageRunning")). Could you try that.

Comment: @Karlta05 I will try this, though you can see I am using this method in other parts of the code - none of these have ever caused exception, only this one. Puzzling !

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK, so I randomly had the exception again after days of not seeing it. At this point the debugger shows the index to be correct : TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOfKey("TabPageRunning") = 2. I'm trying out the .SelectEDTab method suggested above to see if it reoccurs